# How to get returned a value by a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Here is my code

```
function save_current_side(current_side) {
    var result;
    var final = a.b({
        callback: function (a) {
            console.log(a); // its working fine here 
            return a;
        }
    });
}
```

where b is the synchronous function.
I am calling the above function anywhere in the code

```
var saved =  save_current_side(current_side);
```

The variable saved is undefined. How to get returned valued by callback function

Comment: What's `b()`? Is it an asynchronous method?

Comment: What is a.b() in your example?  I am stumped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If `b` is a synchronoys method, you simply store the value in a variable, so that you can return it from the `save_current_side` function instead of from the callback function:

```
function save_current_side(current_side) {
  var result;
  a.b({
    callback: function (a) {
      result = a;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

If `b` is an asynchronous method, you can't return the value from the function, as it doesn't exist yet when you exit the function. Use a callback:

```
function save_current_side(current_side, callback) {
  a.b({
    callback: function (a) {
      callback(a);
    }
  });
}

save_current_side(current_side, function(a){
  console.log(a);
});
```

Comment: Dear Guffa 
How can i use the a value out of the  " save_current_side " after callback??

Comment: @KostantinosIbra: You can't, as the function returns before the callback. You can return whatever you like from the function and use that as normal, but as that happens before the callback you don't have access to the result from the asynchronous call at that time.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to pass the callback as argument in the function as given below

```
function save_current_side(current_side,callback) {
   var result;
   var final = a.b(function(){
      callback(a);
   });
}
```

This is how you can call it anywhere in the code

```
var saved;
save_current_side(current_side,function(saved){
     console.log(saved);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to submit the callback function. Example:

```
function save_current_side(current_side, callback) {        
    a.b({
        callback: callback
    });
}

save_current_side(current_side, function() {
  console.log('saved'):
});
```

Comment: What is a.b()?  or just a()?

Answer (score 2):

Use **Promise**. Once data is read/fetched resolve it. Later, at call point use **then(data)** with resolved value inside. My project example:

```
function getImage(imagename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(`./uploads/${imagename}`, 'utf8', function(err, data){
            if(err) {
                reject(null);
                throw err;
            }
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
        getImage(imagename).then(image => {
            console.log('Img contents: ' + image);
        });
        ....
    });
});
```

Comment: const fs = require('fs');

Comment: upd: To read image as base64: const contents = await fs.promises.readFile(`./uploads/${imagename}`, { encoding: 'base64' });