# function return value is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, return-value

I'm currently working on this function, and the return value returns with *undefined*. I'm not sure if it is my lack of understanding how javascript operates, or it requires some tricky voodoo to make my code work.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var _ = require('underscore');


function eventValue(current, choice) {
 var output = [];

 if (current != null) {


  var json;
  fs.readFile('./json.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
    throw err
   }

   json = JSON.parse(data);

   // filter by ID 
   var filtered = _.filter(json, {
    'ID': current
   });
   //console.log(filtered);

   // Get ID of Object
   var ID = _.pluck(filtered, 'ID');
   // Get Next value of object
   var NEXT = _.pluck(filtered, 'next');


   // get nested 'choice's 'next' value
   var collect = _.pluck(_.filter(
    _.flatten(
     _.pluck(filtered, 'choice')), {
     'choice': choice
    }), 'next');


   var stringID = String(ID);
   var stringNext = String(NEXT + collect);

   output = [stringID, stringNext];

   return output;

  })
 } else console.log("[[error]] please populate eventValue()");
};


var a = eventValue("001001A01B01");
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use value returned from asynchronous function callback which you can not.

Refer: [How to get returned value by function with callback inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182778/how-to-get-returned-value-by-function-with-callback-inside)