# React: How to get value out of function and write it in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a function that can read the duration of a audio file input and then write it in the state. The `getDuration` function works and I can console log the duration of the audio files. However, I have problems to access the duration outside the `getDuration` function.

I would like to do something like this:

```js
onChangeAudioFile(e) {
  this.setState({
    selectedFileDuration: getDuration(e.target.files[0])
  };

  function getDuration(file) {
    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var audio = new Audio([objectURL]);
    var duration = null

    audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
      console.log(audio.duration);
      duration = audio.duration;
    }

    return duration
  }
}
```

I'm able to console log the duration, but I can not bring the value out of the function and write it in my state.

I am happy for any clarification.

Greetings

Comment: Make `getDuration` an `async` function and add `await` before the `getDuration` call when assigning it to `selectedFileDuration`.

Comment: What happens when you run this code? It looks fine to me other than the order. Try moving the function declaration outside of and before  `onChangeAudioFile()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get returned a value by a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182778/how-to-get-returned-a-value-by-a-callback-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `return duration` is executed before the `onloadedmetadata` callback has ever been executed. That event is asynchronous. This is explained in more detail in other Q&As such as

[Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

In your case, instead of getting the value "out" of the callback function, call `setState`, when/where the value is available: in the `onloadedmetadata` event handler:

```
onChangeAudioFile(e) {
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
  var audio = new Audio([objectURL]);

  audio.onloadedmetadata = () => {
    this.setState({
      selectedFileDuration: audio.duration;
    };
  };
}
```

See also [my blog post about callback misconceptions](https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html).

Comment: Or with hooks: `const [ fileDuration, setFileDuration ] = useState(null); ... setFileDuration(audio.duration)`

Comment: Thanks for the additional references @Felix

Answer (score 1):

The `duration` value isn't readily available, you need to create a promise so you can `await` the value returned by `getDuration`.

```js
async onChangeAudioFile(e) {
  this.setState({
    selectedFileDuration: await getDuration(e.target.files[0])
  };

  function getDuration(file) {
    return new Promise((res) => {
      var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      var audio = new Audio([objectURL]);

      audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
        console.log(audio.duration);
        res(audio.duration)
      }
    })
  }
}
```